# How to solve mailing and other delivery channels in DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am wondering where do I need to put email delivering logic in DDD applications? I have the impression that it is in presentation, because it is showing stuff to users and the domain usually does not care about whether the data is presented through a web application, mobile application or email.

Though the channel might affect security and business decisions, e.g. if somebody uses the app, they might get a discount or different security rules are applied to them. Some part of it is certainly presentation because the emails are usually in HTML format. Though I have an impression that it shows up in the application as some sort of delivery channel or maybe as a special type of event or return value.

How do you solve these different delivery channels in your DDD application?

Comment: EmailSenderService? not sure what problem you are having here

Comment: @Ewan Design problem. Currently I have something like `domain.emailService.sendRegistrationMail(userData, oneTimePassword)` and I think it is not the right solution. I have proper layers for the webapplication: presentation, application, domain, infrastructure. I don't think that sending the registration mail is a domain concern.

Comment: @Ewan Maybe it should be in the application layer something like `application.channels.mail.send(UserRegistrationDTO, oneTimePassword)`. It definitely shows up in the presentation as `RegistrationMailViewModel`, `RegistrationMailHtmlTemplate` and the view model has dependency injection with the `UserRegistrationDTO`, which is created in the application layer. I am just not sure where to say explicitly in the code, that this DTO must be sent in this mailing channel. Same with the password reset email. Maybe the presentation must decide it, maybe the application.

Comment: @Ewan Maybe I need something like hexagonal architecture add a port which delivers the `UserRegistered` event and add a mailing adapter which handles it, but it is too late to change the code this way. Currently I just do normal calls and return values contain the DTO, so I have only the HTTP response channel, multiple channels like HTTP response, email, logs, etc. are not supported. I wonder if there is a general DDD solution or pattern or best practice for this. E.g. for committing changes there is the unit of work pattern.

Comment: forgetting DDD for the moment. you would want a second application to send the emails

Comment: @Ewan It is just a few emails, so not in this case, though some logic would be useful for delivery or rollback. E.g. if somebody registers and they don't click on the confirmation link for a week, then automatically cancelling the registration or resending the confirmation email, etc. The main feature is booking on the site, so ofc. customers are part of the domain, but I am not sure whether I can make abstract terms from these email confirmation stuff which could belong to the domain. I was able to make proper abstractions, VOs and entities from other things like OpenDays, BookingDays, etc.

Comment: you need a separate applicaiton becuase of the slowness of email sending. its doesnt conflict with DDD, I htink you need to include some sample code

Comment: @Ewan I think the main reason I need an email address, because it is a secondary channel if they cannot login or to notify them for certain events involving their accounts. I could use facebook chat or telegram or a mobile app too. Maybe I can put this part into the domain as an abstraction.

Comment: @Ewan Ohh okay. This is just a little project with around 1000 users atm. It does not require DDD, I just try to practice DDD on it before I use it on bigger projects. I can add a sample code later.

Answer (score 2):

There are two point of views:

- email channel is just one possible implementation of a notification. For the domain, it only matters that users are notified, regardless how. Thus, the email channel is an implementation detail  ot relevant for the domain design.
- email channel is relevant for the domain, because to benefit from elail notification, you need to think getting the email in the customer account, as you would need the phone for SMS notification, or on the other (hypothetical?) extreme, the postal address for a notification by paper mail. Maybe the customer wants to chose the preferred notification scheme. Maybe some business rules apply (e.g. "sms only if requested and customer is premium").

So the best would be to separate the concerns. In the subdomain requiring the notification, you'll just have a notification event without channel choice details . In the subdomain of customer management, you'll define very well the channel, and all the kind of addresses/contact details needed.

Answer (score 1):

I added an interface to the application to deliver information on a different communication channel than HTTP response. I'll inject it from the presentation when the implementation is available.

```
namespace application;

use application\UserReadTransferWithToken;

interface iEmailService {
    public function sendRegistrationMail(UserReadTransferWithToken $transfer);
    public function sendPasswordResetMail(UserReadTransferWithToken $transfer);
}
```

I don't think in my case this is a domain concern, though the application layer must contain some info about the different delivery method and send the data transfer objects through it. The presentation what builds and sends the actual emails based on the data and email templates. When I scale this out it is possible to send the mails through a different application using a different implementation of the interface and probably a message queue, but in my current project I don't think it will happen. In my security subdomain this could show up as `SecureCommunicationChannelTo(user).send(oneTimePassword)` or something like this if I want to make this really abstract, but for now it is ok to stop here.